# Not able to simulate my sdf file in ignition gazebo

Tags: gazebo-ignition, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Continuing the question from https://community.gazebosim.org/t/not-able-to-simulate-my-sdf-file-in-ignition-gazebo/813

I was trying to simulate an animal(file attached below) in ignition gazebo by adding it to the empty_world.sdf file as explained in the tutorial https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/sdf_worlds#sdf-worlds.

The error I am getting is given below

```
[Err] [Server.cc:181] Error Code 13 Msg: Directory doesn’t exist[goat.dae]
[GUI] [Err] [PathManager.cc:57] Service call timed out for [/gazebo/resource_paths/get]
```

The code I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.7">
    <world name="world_demo">
      <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
           <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
           <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
      </physics>
      <plugin
          filename="libignition-gazebo-physics-system.so"
          name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics">
       </plugin>
       <plugin
          filename="libignition-gazebo-user-commands-system.so"
          name="ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands">
        </plugin>
        <plugin
          filename="libignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system.so"
          name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
        </plugin>

         <gui fullscreen="0">

           <!-- 3D scene -->
         <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
          <ignition-gui>
              <title>3D View</title>
              <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
              <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
          </ignition-gui>

          <engine>ogre2</engine>
          <scene>scene</scene>
          <ambient_light>1.0 1.0 1.0</ambient_light>
          <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
          <camera_pose>-6 0 6 0 0.5 0</camera_pose>
        </plugin>

        <!-- World control -->
        <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
          <ignition-gui>
            <title>World control</title>
            <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
            <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
            <property type="double" key="height">72</property>
            <property type="double" key="width">121</property>
            <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

            <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
            <anchors target="3D View">
              <line own="left" target="left"/>
              <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
            </anchors>
          </ignition-gui>

          <play_pause>true</play_pause>
          <step>true</step>
          <start_paused>true</start_paused>
          <service>/world/world_demo/control</service>
          <stats_topic>/world_demo/world_demo/stats</stats_topic>

        </plugin>

        <!-- World statistics -->
        <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
            <ignition-gui>
                <title>World stats</title>
                <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
                <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
                <property type="double" key="height">110</property>
                <property type="double" key="width">290</property>
                <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

                <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
                <anchors target="3D View">
                <line own="right" target="right"/>
                <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
                </anchors>
            </ignition-gui>

            <sim_time>true</sim_time>
            <real_time>true</real_time>
            <real_time_factor>true</real_time_factor>
            <iterations>true</iterations>
            <topic>/world/world_demo/stats</topic>

        </plugin>

        <!-- Entity tree -->
        <plugin filename="EntityTree" name="Entity tree">
        </plugin>
      </gui>

      <!--light-->
      <light type="directional" name="sun">
        <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
        <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
        <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
        <attenuation>
          <range>1000</range>
          <constant>0.9</constant>
          <linear>0.01</linear>
          <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
        </attenuation>
        <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
      </light>

      <include>
         <uri>
             model://goat.dae
         </uri>
      </include>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

ignition gazebo version I am using

```
Ignition Gazebo, version 4.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2.0 License.
```

Note: I tried adding the file to my workspace ~/ign-gazebo/examples/worlds but it still didn't work. I am able to simulate all the other files.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26547/not-able-to-simulate-my-sdf-file-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-02-11**:
Maybe it should be in a separate folder? So `model://goat/goat.dae`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

These lines in your `sdf` file are wrong:

```
  <include>
     <uri>
         model://goat.dae
     </uri>
  </include>
```

You can't add a mesh in that way. You should include a model with the visual and collisions, etc or create a package with the model. You can find here a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model) about how to create your own model.

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2021-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0